# Attached event listener on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events, mouseevent

I'm very new to Javascript and is trying to attach an anonymous function to an event listener. What the function does is that when `mouseover` the first element, a message will be displayed in the second element depending on the length of the text within the first element.

However, when I hover my mouse over the first element, nothing happens. Because I'm new to JavaScript, I'm not sure what I did wrong.

```js
    function checkLength(event, minLength){
        var el, elementTwo;
        el = event.target;
        elementTwo = el.nextSibling;
        
        if(el.value.length < minLength){
            elementTwo.innerHTML = "not enough";
        } else {
            elementTwo.innerHTML = "enough";
        }
    }
    
    var elUserName = document.getElementById("one");
    elUserName.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){
        checkLength(event, 5);
    }, false);
```

```html
    <div>
        <div id="one">Bob</div>
        <div id="two"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the `text` of the element you use `textContent`. `value` is for inputs.

Also, you need to select the next element sibling, not just the next sibling node.

```js
function checkLength(event, minLength){
        var el, elementTwo;
        el = event.target;
        elementTwo = el.nextElementSibling;
        
        if(el.textContent.length < minLength){
            elementTwo.innerHTML = "not enough";
        } else {
            elementTwo.innerHTML = "enough";
        }
    }
    
    var elUserName = document.getElementById("one");
    elUserName.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){
        checkLength(event, 5);
    }, false);
```

```html
<div>
        <div id="one">Bob</div>
        <div id="two"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out! May i ask, how did you got to know the answer? Just that next time I encounter a problem like this, I really wish I can solve it on my own. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Well, I solved it out of my own experience but when I'm facing problems I haven't seen or deal with them before I debug the application. Finding answers for the problem is usually not the hardest thing, finding the real problems is usually the hardest .

Comment: thanks for sharing your wisdom and thanks again for helping out! really appreciate it.